# Jenkins service always pending on minikube

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, minikube

I installed `minikube` on local.

Dashboard is 192.168.99.100:30000

I installed Jenkins by helm:

```
$ helm install stable/jenkins
```

Then the service always pending:

```
$ kubectl get services --namespace=default -w wandering-buffoon-jenkins
NAME                        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                          AGE
wandering-buffoon-jenkins   10.0.0.153   <pending>     8080:31326/TCP,50000:31090/TCP   26m
```

Why? So can't use external-ip to access it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm guessing that you didn't update the parameters to use `NodePort` instead of the default `LoadBalancer`. The minikube cluster doesn't support the `LoadBalancer` type so Kubernetes is looping trying to create a load balancer to get an external IP.

Use helm to see the options for the stable/jenkins chart:

```
$ helm inspect values stable/jenkins
# Default values for jenkins.
...
# For minikube, set this to NodePort, elsewhere use LoadBalancer
# Use ClusterIP if your setup includes ingress controller
  ServiceType: LoadBalancer
...
```

You can set this by doing something like this:

```
$ echo $'Master:\n  ServiceType: NodePort' > config.yaml
$ helm install -f config.yaml stable/jenkins
```

Comment: Thank you very much! So if try other soft, such as GitLab, it seems that should do the same thing.

Comment: But after I tried your method, The `ServiceType` is also `LoadBalancer`, not changed.

Comment: Sorry I was a little off on the config.yaml. Edited!

Comment: Thank you. Has no lucky:( This time: `invited-deer-jenkins         10.0.0.186   <nodes>       8080:30321/TCP,50000:32021/TCP   2m`. The `EXTERNAL-IP` shows `nodes`. And the inspect message is still `ServiceType: LoadBalancer`. I deleted that pod and installed again. Maybe the config not works.

Comment: It seems to be working for me: https://gist.github.com/coreypobrien/7e96acdbba72932566884a10a8793593

Comment: I tried again. It works today! The result was the same as yours. Thank you very much!

Comment: Done with:
`helm install stable/jenkins --set Master.ServiceType=NodePort`
Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Here is a single command for lazy people who do not want to create the separate config.yaml file

```
helm install --name jenkins --set Master.ServiceType=NodePort stable/jenkins
```

In case there are more than one option which you want to set, provide them as comma-separated

```
helm install --name jenkins --set Master.ServiceType=NodePort,Persistence.Enabled=false stable/jenkins
```

Also see the option available which you can set [here](http://helm%20install%20--name%20jenkins%20--set%20Master.ServiceType=NodePort,Persistence.Enabled=false%20stable/jenkins). This is same as helm inspect command but more readable since available as a web page