# Kubernetes error: "Master.* values have been renamed, please check the documentation"

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

**What I'm trying to do:** Trying to install Jenkins locally in minikube using helm.

The commands I'm using:

```
root@-Unix:/# echo $'Master:\n  serviceType: NodePort' > config.yaml (also tried with 'ServiceType')
root@-Unix:/# helm install --name jenkins-1 -f config.yaml stable/jenkins
```

**The issue I'm facing:** According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43940123/8494729) post, I'm trying to change ServiceType form `LoadBalancer` to `NodePort` but I'm getting following error:

> Error: render error in "jenkins/templates/deprecation.yaml": template:
>   jenkins/templates/deprecation.yaml:258:11: executing
>   "jenkins/templates/deprecation.yaml" at : error calling fail:
>   Master.* values have been renamed, please check the documentation

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Option I.

```
helm install --name jenkins-1 --set Master.ServiceType=NodePort stable/jenkins
```

Option II.

Let helm to install service of the LoadBalancer type and then manually edit it

`kubectl edit svc jenkins-svc` and set `type: NodePort`